# Youtube datasets example with keyword field

Tags: youtube, dataset

I'm working on a data mining project, and I need to download youtube datasets to work on. I want at least 300 entry to work on. 
I've tried googling it but I couldn't find any keywords fields included in it.
Does anyone know where to download such datasets??